# ChannelImages Fatal Error PHP 7

Tags: ee2, channel-images, php-errors

I'm getting the following fatal error when trying to load EE 2.11.2 with ChannelImages 5.4.19 under PHP 7/7.1:

> Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in /home/omart/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/image_helper.php on line 913

Here is the code snippet in question. Line is 913 is the last if statement:

```
//----------------------------------------
        // Channel?
        //----------------------------------------
        if (strpos($param_channel, '|') !== FALSE)
        {
            $channel_id = array();
            $temp = explode('|', $param_channel);

            foreach($temp as $item)
            {
                if (isset($channels[$item]) == FALSE) continue;
                $channel_id[] = $channels[$item];
            }

            return $channel_id;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isset($channels[$param_channel]) == FALSE) continue;
            else return $channels[$param_channel];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace code `continue;` with `return false;` statement.